# display progress indicator until data are available with Flow and Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Flow<List<Tasks>>` that I am observing in a composable:

```
val tasks by viewModel.tasks().collectAsStateWithLifecycle(emptyList())
```

How do I display a progress indicator until the tasks is available?
So far I am doing something like this:

```
if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
        Text("No tasks")
    } else {
        //Column with tasks
    }
```

Sometimes I get the `Text("No tasks")` for a couple a milliseconds before the list of tasks appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
sealed interface HomeUiState {
object Loading : HomeUiState
data class Success(val tasks: List<Task>) : HomeUiState
}

@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
 private val repository: AppRepository
 ) : ViewModel() {

val uiState: StateFlow<HomeUiState> = tasks().map {
    Success(it)
}.stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = Loading
)
```

And in my composable:

```
val uiState by homeViewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    when (uiState) {
        HomeUiState.Loading -> //Display circular indicator
        is HomeUiState.Success -> //Display composable with list of tasks
         //do tasks = (uiState as HomeUiState.Success).tasks to retrieve the list of tasks.
        )
    }
```

The idea came from the [Now In Android](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) sample app.